# How to get each comments of different document as separate in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am creating a social web using Node js and mongoDB. I have three tables as `events`, `projects` and `reactions`(like, comment).

Every `event` has many projects and every `project` has many `reactions`.

**events**

```
|----|---------|-------------|
| id | title   | description |
|----|---------|-------------|
| e1 | event 1 |             |
| e2 | event 2 | descc       |
| e3 | event 3 |             |
|----|---------|-------------|
```

**projects**

```
|----|-----------|-------------|----------|
| id | project   | description | event_id |
|----|-----------|-------------|----------|
| p1 | project 1 | sample      | e1       |
| p2 | project 2 | sample      | e1       |
| p3 | project 3 | sample      | e1       |
| p4 | project 1 | sample      | e2       |
|----|-----------|-------------|----------|
```

**reactions**

```
|----|----------|------------|----------|--------|-------|
| id | user_id  | project_id | event_id | type   | value |
|----|----------|------------|----------|--------|-------|
| 1  |   user1  |     p1     |    e1    | comment| nice  |
| 2  |   user1  |     p1     |    e1    | comment| wow   |
| 3  |   user2  |     p1     |    e1    | like   |   1   |
| 4  |   user2  |     p1     |    e2    | comment| good  |
| 5  |   user1  |     p2     |    e1    | comment| nice  |
| 6  |   user3  |     p1     |    e1    | comment| nice  |
| 7  |   user4  |     p1     |    e1    | like   |   1   |
| 8  |   user4  |     p1     |    e1    | comment| bad   |
| 9  |   user5  |     p2     |    e1    | comment| enjoy |
| 10 |   user3  |     p2     |    e1    | comment| happy |
|----|----------|------------|----------|--------|-------|
```

**my code**

```
try
    {
        const id = req.params.id;
        var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

        if(!ObjectId.isValid(id))
        {
            return res.status(503).json("Invalid ID");
        } 

        var aggregate = Event.aggregate();

        aggregate.match({"_id":ObjectId(id)})
        .lookup({ from: "pojects", localField: "_id", foreignField: "event_id",as: "project_doc"})
        .lookup({from: "user_reactins", localField: "_id", foreignField: "event_id", as: "reactions"})
        .lookup({from: "user_reactins", localField: "project_doc._id", foreignField: "project_id", as: "pro_reactions"})
        .addFields({"project_doc.totalComments": "$pro_reactions"})


        .project({_id:"$_id",title:"$title", project_doc:"$project_doc",

        total_like_event: {
            "$size": {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$reactions",
                    as: "s",
                    cond: {
                        $eq: ["$$s.key", "like"]
                    },

                }
            }
        },

        total_comment_event: {
            "$size": {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$reactions",
                    as: "s",
                    cond: {
                        $eq: ["$$s.key", "comment"]
                    },

                }
            }
        }

    })

        var options = {}

        Event.aggregatePaginate(aggregate, options, function(err, results, pageCount, count)
        {
            return res.status(200).json({data:results[0],pro_status:statusResult,eve_status:eveResult,eve_cat:categoryResult});
        }) 
    }
    catch (err)
    {
        return res.status(500).json(err);
    }
```

this is my end point `http://url/api/events/e1`

If I used this end point, I want all comments for the given event(`e1`) by categorized by project as follows

```
{
    "data": {
        "_id": "e1",
        "title": "event 1",
        "project_doc": [
            {
                "_id": "p1",
                "title": "project 1",
                "description": "sample",                
                "totalComments": [
                    {
                        "_id": "1",
                        "user_id": "user1",
                        "programme_id": "p1",
                        "key": "comment",
                        "value": "nice",
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "2",
                        "user_id": "user1",
                        "programme_id": "p1",
                        "key": "comment",
                        "value": "wow",
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "6",
                        "user_id": "user3",
                        "programme_id": "p1",
                        "key": "comment",
                        "value": "nice",
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "1",
                        "user_id": "user1",
                        "programme_id": "p1",
                        "key": "comment",
                        "value": "nice",
                    }
                ]
            },
        ],

        "total_view_event": 0,
        "total_like_event": 1,
        "total_comment_event": 4
    }
}
```